# How to save a changed assembly using Mono.Cecil?

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil

I have a version of [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) which does not have the `AssemblyFactory` class. Probably it is the 0.9 version of the Cecil class. Is there a way out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `AssemblyDefinition.Write(fileName)`